# Spinner passing wrong fields to my firestore database android studio java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-spinner

I have a firestore document that contain 2 fields : name and link.
I populate a spinner with this document.

- When i populate the name, it pass me the name to my other firestore database.
- When i populate the link, it pass me the link to my other firestore database.

I want to show the name on the spinner, but when i add a data to other firestore it add the link not the name.

here is the firestore :
[image]

here is my code :

```
public class CreateData extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText League , Team1 , Team2 , Tip ;
    MaterialButton Registerbtn;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_data);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        League = findViewById(R.id.league);
        Team1 = findViewById(R.id.team1);
        Team2 = findViewById(R.id.team2);
        Tip = findViewById(R.id.tip);
        //Id = findViewById(R.id.idtip);
        Registerbtn = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference imagesRef = db.collection("images");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercountry);
        List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> imagelink = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptername = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, imageList);
        adaptername.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adaptername);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterlink = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, imagelink);
        adapterlink.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterlink);
        imagesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String images = document.getString("name");
                        imageList.add(images);
                        String links = document.getString("pic");
                        imagelink.add(links);
                    }
                    adapterlink.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        Registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //String id = Id.getText().toString();
                String league = League.getText().toString();
                String team1 = Team1.getText().toString();
                String team2 = Team2.getText().toString();
                String tip = Tip.getText().toString();
                String links = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Map<String,Object> tips = new HashMap<>();
                //tips.put("Document ID",id);
                tips.put("league",league);
                tips.put("team1",team1);
                tips.put("team2",team2);
                tips.put("tip",tip);
                tips.put("image",links);
                tips.put("Created at", new Timestamp(new Date()));

                db.collection("tips")
                        .add(tips)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(CreateData.this,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(CreateData.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: the code works fine .. listen : i need to show the images name in the spinner but pass the image link to the other firestore database ..

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the image link to the other firestore database"?

Comment: sir i rewrite the question . you could recheck